Is Gauss law constraint in gauging a global symmetry on lattice a dynamical constraint or a kinematical constraint?
Suppose a lattice system is $G$-symmetric, when we try to gauge this symmetry, we follow the following steps (for example toric code Levin Gu Xie Chen):

minimal coupling: the original Hamiltonian is coupled to the background gauge field;
zero-flux constraint: adding another term in the Hamiltonian, such that the flux is conserved
gauss law: there are two possible approaches: imposing it energetically or imposing it by restricting the Hilbert space.

However, imposing it by restricting the Hilbert space would cause the resulting Hilbert space to be non-tensor product (at least the restricted Hilbert space does not carry a natural tensor product structure) , which is not acceptable in the usual lattice system.
How people with different background view this problem?
